# Can express app.listen(...) be moved to command line

Tags: node.js, express, flask

The express hello world example from [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) works perfect:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

// Isn't this "listen" part boilerplate ?
// Can it be moved to the command line invocation ?
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

When I compare it to [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application), it seems the `listen`-ing part is implicit:

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

# no explicit 'listen' is needed
```

Can I "move" the `listen`-ing code to the command line invocation ?

```bash
$ node app.js --listen-on-port=3000 # something like that
```

Comment: Exactly as you asked: probably not really. You can parse command line arguments though. Is there something specific you want to do or are you just trying to save a line of code.

Comment: @Evert I'm mostly trying to learn best practices, and thuoght I might be missing something

Comment: Your Flask example won't do anything though if run directly from the command line.  It's the `flask run` command that does the listening for you.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom in that case, the best practice is to just call listen (and optionally allow the port to be supplied via an environment variable).

Comment: @AKX yes, I guess I meant to ask is there any equivalent along the lines of `express run` ... It seems there isn't. Thanks !

Comment: @OrenIshShalom Yeah, there isn't, nor is there a generic app server like `gunicorn` is in Python land, because there isn't a WSGI-like protocol in Node land.